# Pagination links breaking search results coming from post data cakephp

Tags: cakephp, post

When I've Search my listing i'm getting some results with pagination, but when i go for second page my search is 
breaking as it was a get request where i'm getting the search results via post method.

**Note:** For getting search results I don't want to submit the form via get request (i.e. Query string params) and also don't want to store the form data in session

Is there any way to get the results which satisfy the above conditions ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement [the PRG Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

> Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a web development design pattern that
>   prevents some duplicate form submissions, creating a more intuitive
>   interface for user agents (users). PRG implements bookmarks and the
>   refresh button in a predictable way that does not create duplicate
>   form submissions.

[The CakeDC Search plugin](https://github.com/cakedc/search) makes that pretty easy to do in CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very hard to do it using only "POST" calls. You'll need to transfor your POST into a GET call.

Check [this post](http://www.pabloleanomartinet.com/cakephp-2-x-filter-basic-search-example/) i made or [clone it from github](https://github.com/pleasedontbelong/cakephp2.x-filter-search-example)

Hope this helps

*EDIT:*

Using my git repo. If you want url querystrings instead of named parameters:

- in [this line](https://github.com/pleasedontbelong/cakephp2.x-filter-search-example/blob/master/app/Controller/MoviesController.php#L26), instead of the foreach build the querystring and pass it to the redirect
- in [this line](https://github.com/pleasedontbelong/cakephp2.x-filter-search-example/blob/master/app/Controller/MoviesController.php#L38), get the parameters from the query string ($GET)
- and in [this line](https://github.com/pleasedontbelong/cakephp2.x-filter-search-example/blob/master/app/Controller/MoviesController.php#L56) add `page`, `sort` and `direction` to  `this->paginate`

I haven't tested it, but it should be something like that

Comment: Is it possible with querystring params instead of named parameters ?

Comment: sure.. why not? but you'll have to manually pass the page, sort and direction to the paginator in your controller

Comment: Could you tell me how it's possible ?

Comment: Added more explanation on my response

Comment: How to build querystring here, since I'm not that much familiar in making a GET request url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814777/cake-php-redirect-with-parameters-in-url

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with a patch.

In Views :

create search form :

```
$this->Form->create('Search', array('url' => array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'index', substr(time(), 2,rand(1, 7) ))) );
```

Note : A random number appended at the end of the form action. This will let us know when to clear session.

in Controller :

```
 public function index( $search = null)
 {        
    $conditions =   array(1 => 1);      
    if( !empty($this->data['Search']['keyword']) && $search)
    {
        $conditions = array('Model.field like' => $this->data['Search']['keyword'] . '%');
        // store search array in session
        $this->Session->write('conditions', $this->data['Search']);
    }           
    if ($search)
    {
        $this->request->data['Search']  =   $this->Session->read('conditions');
        $conditions = array('Model.field like' => $this->data['Search']['keyword'] . '%');    
    }
    else
    {
        $conditions =   array(1 => 1);  
        $this->Session->delete('conditions');
    }    
    $this->paginate= array('limit'=> 10, 'conditions' => $conditions);
    $lists = $this->Paginate('Model');
 }
```

Hope you understand the logic behind.