# cakePHP pagination links - manual pagine

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I want to page through the records, using ajax with submitted filters. however, I don't want to use cake's js helpers.

What is the way to do it?

How can I get cake to remember the filters? (keep in mind that i want to use links, like cake, and not submitting data again)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination links breaking search results coming from post data cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332714/pagination-links-breaking-search-results-coming-from-post-data-cakephp). The fact you're wanting to use js doesn't change how you do it.

Comment: hi @AD7six, this is not a duplicate because my main question is not "how to fix it?" but, "how it is done?" and "what are the basics?"

Comment: in what way is that different than the first answer?

Comment: @AD7six the answer & attached link are great, but they are an alternate way, and not an explanation about cake's way. 
I dont want to create an alternate pagination..

Comment: If the linked duplicate isn't the answer your question isn't clear.