# hide url param cakephp with refresh

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

how do you hide / unhide / mask URL query parameters in cakephp? 
I've tried with javascript but still error when I tried the following pages of his.

view and controller

pastebin.com/8XEBzQSU

pastebin.com/pEjcU5ma

http://www.mywebsite.com/web/index/page:2?url=web

`hide` `index/page:2?url=web`

view

```
    </p>

        <?php
        $params = $this->Paginator->params();
        if ($params['pageCount'] > 1) {
        ?>
        <div>
        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
            <?php
                echo $this->Paginator->prev('&larr; Previous', array('class' => 'prev','tag' => 'li','escape' => false), '<a onclick="return false;">&larr; Previous</a>', array('class' => 'prev disabled','tag' => 'li','escape' => false));
                echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '','tag' => 'li','currentClass' => 'active','currentTag' => 'a'));
                echo $this->Paginator->next('Next &rarr;', array('class' => 'next','tag' => 'li','escape' => false), '<a onclick="return false;">Next &rarr;</a>', array('class' => 'next disabled','tag' => 'li','escape' => false));
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

controllers

```
if (isset($tmp) && $tmp){
            array_push($paginate['conditions'], $tmp);
        }

        //print_r($paginate);

        $this->paginate = $paginate;
    }
    $this->set('web', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. What should your URL look like ?

Comment: hide parameters /index/page:id

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX Pagination if you do not want to use GET request to paginate.

or alternatively, have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332714/pagination-links-breaking-search-results-coming-from-post-data-cakephp)